# Rest API call C#/VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, rest, httpwebrequest

Can anyone help me how to write request for this call ?

```
<form method="POST" action="https://creator.zoho.eu/api/sampleapps/json/sample/form/Employee/record/update">
<input type="hidden" name ="authtoken" value="**********">
<input type="hidden" name ="scope" id="scope" value="creatorapi">
<input type="text" name="criteria" value="Name=Gary">

<input type="text" name="Basic" value="20000">
<input type="text" name="Address" value="UK">

<input type="submit" value="Update Record">
</form>
```

I tried as a standard [HTTPWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-request-data-using-the-webrequest-class) but keep throwing me errors.

I'm not close to web requests but i think i need to split Web URL and content of body.

The example mention above is HTML code so im really confused.

Original link : [ZOHO Creator](https://www.zoho.eu/creator/help/api/rest-api/rest-api-edit-records.html)

EDIT:

```
    Dim apiUrl As String = "https://creator.zoho.eu/api/updaterowtest/json/sample/form/UntitledForm/record/update"

    Dim xmlprepared As String = <![CDATA[         
            <input type="hidden" name ="authtoken" value="1514ea937db6b">
            <input type="hidden" name ="scope" id="scope" value="creatorapi">
            <input type="text" name="criteria" value="Code=123">

            <input type="text" name="Updated" value="Yes">

            <input type="submit" value="Update Record">
            </form>]]>.Value

    Dim res As String = getResponseFromUrl(apiUrl, xmlprepared)

 Public Function getResponseFromUrl(ByVal url As String, ByVal params As String)
        Dim str As String = ""
        Try
            Dim webreq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
            webreq.Method = "POST"
            webreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(params)
            Dim dataStream As Stream = webreq.GetRequestStream()
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
            dataStream.Close()

            Dim res As WebResponse = webreq.GetResponse()
            Dim stream As Stream = res.GetResponseStream()
            Dim streamReader As New StreamReader(stream)
            str = streamReader.ReadToEnd
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Return str.ToString
    End Function
```

Comment: If you show what you've tried, and which errors `HttpWebRequest` throws you, I'm quite sure someone can help you.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I put this string as my text for web request ? . Sec i will update the post with code itried

Comment: @C.Evenhuis This is my request and response is : Bad request...